# How to deploy elastic search on openshift?

Tags: elasticsearch, deployment, openshift, devops

I have been trying to deploy elastic search on openshift, but I am facing certain issues as the pod is terminated with the code 137 (OOM killed).

Also I am facing issues while increasing the VM_max_map_count for the same.

Can someone guide me on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

**OOM issues**:
Could you check your `deploymentConfig` or `deployment` for `elasticsearch` ?
And then decrease the `memory size` under `resources` section, look the following sample yaml.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Deployment
spec:
  containers:
  - image: openshift/elasticsearch
    name: elasticsearch
    resources:
      requests:
        memory: 16Gi 
      limits: 
        memory: 16Gi 
      ...
```

**vm.max_map_count issue**: it can be resolved the following steps, reger [UPDATING THE NODE CONFIGURATION](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/servicemesh-install/servicemesh-install.html#updating-node-configuration)
 for more details.

- Create a file named /etc/sysctl.d/99-elasticsearch.conf with the following contents:

  `vm.max_map_count = 262144`
- Execute the following command:

  `$ sysctl vm.max_map_count=262144`

Comment: I don't have the access rights to change in the nodes. Is there any other possible way to change the vm.max_map_count?

Comment: AFAIK vm.max_map_count is required to access a running host as root account. How about you ask to your system administrator.